# How to get all the information in fewer rows when joining three tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone help me in writing Oracle SQL Query for the following scenario:

1. Company can have multiple departments.
2. Each department can have multiple Employees.
3. Employee need not have department assigned but company Id is must.

This is the output I am trying for:

[image]

This is the query I have tried So far:

```
SELECT C.id   Company_Id, 
       C.name Company_Name, 
       D.id   Department_Id, 
       D.name Department_Name, 
       E.id   Employee_Id, 
       E.name Employee_Name 
FROM   Company C 
       FULL OUTER JOIN Department D 
                    ON D.CompanyId = C.Id 
       FULL OUTER JOIN Employee E 
                    ON E.CompanyId = C.Id AND E.DepartmentId = D.Id
ORDER BY Company_Id,Department_Id,Employee_Id;
```

But it gives this output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df238/3/0

Comment: It is good that you added sqlfiddle, although I don't know when you added it. But, it is always better to post sample data in text format rather than images. In many workplace computers, the images may not open due to restrictions and it is hard to recreate the scenario with images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to convert `ON E.CompanyId = C.Id AND E.DepartmentId = D.Id` join condition to
   `ON E.CompanyId = C.Id AND ( E.DepartmentId = D.Id OR E.DepartmentId is null )`

```
SELECT C.id   Company_Id, 
       C.name Company_Name, 
       D.id   Department_Id, 
       D.name Department_Name, 
       E.id   Employee_Id, 
       E.name Employee_Name 
FROM   Company C 
       FULL OUTER JOIN Department D 
                    ON D.CompanyId = C.Id 
       FULL OUTER JOIN Employee E 
                    ON E.CompanyId = C.Id AND ( E.DepartmentId = D.Id OR E.DepartmentId is null )
ORDER BY Company_Id,Department_Id,Employee_Id;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df238/38)

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is what I need.